# Efficient WebView resizing

Tags: android, android-webview, android-toolbar, android-scroll, android-measure

I've implemented floating `Toolbar` in my app (hides with scroll down, shows on up) and now I see some flickering views inside `WebView`, to be precise these sticked to the bottom. I've noticed that this happens when I'm resizing `WebView` due to `Toolbar` offset change like this:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

@Override
public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    boolean scrollFlagsSet = ((AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) getToolbar().getLayoutParams()).
            getScrollFlags() != 0;
    int bottom = (!scrollFlagsSet ? 0 : getToolbarHeightAttr()) + verticalOffset;
    swipeRefreshLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, bottom);
    swipeRefreshLayout.requestLayout();
}
```

`swipeRefreshLayout` is `WebView`s parent. Method causes proper resizing `WebView` and it's pretty efficient, no lags (EDIT: a bit laggy on older devices). But when `WebView` loads site with some views sticked to the bottom then these views are flickering when resizing occurs. I can even see text in gap between bottom `WebView`s edge (gap present when scrolling down, view are cutted on the bottom when scrolling up). I've catched this behavior on screens (blue - `Toolbar`, gray - `WebView`, light blue & orange - in-webview views sticked to bottom). It looks like this only for a couple of millis (one frame?) and get back to the bottom fixed position. How to fix this?

[image: scrolling gap]

Same page loaded in Chrome or Firefox behaves correctly, these views are sticked to bottom and have fixed position, doesn't flicker with scroll/toolbar offset change

I'm using [this `NestedWebView`](https://gist.github.com/alexmiragall/0c4c7163f7a17938518ce9794c4a5236). My app uses a lot of fragments loaded into `Activities`, which all are extending abstract `BaseActivity` in which I have `CoordinatorLayout`. `WebViews` belong to fragments and are placed in different containers, there is no option to place `WebView` straight into `CoordinatorLayout`

edit: XMLs

activity:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_cooridnator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />
```

fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_webview_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <my.package.widgets.web.NestedWebView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_webview_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

Comment: Could you please provide the XML layout files?

Comment: I'm pretty shure that XMLs are unrelated, but I've posted both for `Activity` and `Fragment`. In fact after own reserach I'm pretty shure that it can't be done without own Chromium implementation, sadly...

Comment: Preload WebView page
In case you are loading the WebView later (after resizing Toolbar), consider preloading its contents.

Comment: well, page loading  takes more time and is "more noticeable" that this "jump", thats not a solution at all... this is the case when `WebView` is already initialised and have loaded content/web page, then user starts scrolling

Comment: GeckoDisplay has method setVerticalClipping(int clippingHeight) we want similar functionality for WebView. https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoDisplay.html#setVerticalClipping-int-